# Understanding differences in Geodetic (WGS84) to ECEF equations?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, geodesy

Methods suggested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752271/distance-between-two-cities-on-earth), [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636993/different-ways-for-calculating-distance-between-two-geodetic-points-give-me-diff) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates) all recommend the following:

$$x = R \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi)$$
$$y = R \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)$$
$$z = R \sin(\theta),$$

where latitude is $\theta$, longitude is $\phi$ and the Earth's approximate radius is $R$ (6371km).

However, I am not sure why these equations are using $R$ rather than their [documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) form:

$$x = (N(\theta) + h) \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi)$$
$$y = (N(\theta) + h) \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)$$
$$z = \left(\frac{b^2}{a^2} N(\theta) + h\right) \sin(\theta),$$

where altitude is $h$, semi-major axis is $a$, semi-minor axis is $b$ and the prime vertical radius of curvature is $N(\theta)$. Further, we can say:

$$N(\theta) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-{e^2}\sin^{2}(\theta)}}$$
and...
$$e^2 = 1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}$$
thus...
$$z = (1 - e^2)  (N(\theta) + h)  \sin(\theta).$$

Now for my purposes, I am treating all points with an altitude of 1, so the $h$ can be eliminated. What I am not comprehending is how they are arriving at:

$$N(\theta) = R$$

and...

$$(1-e^2) * N(\theta) = R$$

Is it safe to use the radius of the Earth as an approximation or should I use the WGS84 constraints (semi-major and first eccentricity) in my computations?

Comment: This is a three dimensional analogue of approximating an ellipse with a circle. You can do it, and for large enough ellipses whose axes are about the same size it may work well, but it's still an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Comments

The earth is not perfectly spherical. There is a flattening at the poles.

The WGS84 modifies spherical coordinates in two ways.

First in order to take into account the equatorial bulge through eccentricity factor $e$.

Secondly if distances are measured from an aircraft or spacecraft at an altitude $h$ above the earth this altitude should be added on to earth's radius.

Parallel lines unlike meridians are not geodesics even in the ideal spherical earth model $(e=0)$. At higher latitudes distance measured along latitudes and shortest path geodesic is more pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $e^2$ for the Earth is roughly $6.6\times 10^{-3}$, so that multiplied by the Earth radius is the order of 40 kilometers. As long as you don't care about missing your positions by such a margin, it does not matter whether the Earth is approximated by a sphere. As soon as you need higher accuracy, the full WGS84 equations are needed.

In addition it is very important to understand that the latitude angles in the WGS equations are *not* geocentric, so the $\theta$ in the two coordinate systems do not have the same values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your additional note? I understand that latitude is not geocentric (they converge at the poles), but what do you mean they do not have the same values?

Comment: I mean that taking a triple $(x,y,z)$ of geocentric Cartesian coordinates, and then calculating the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in the WGS84 system on one hand and the spherical coordinate system on the other, the two values of $\varphi$ will be the same but not the two values of the $\theta$ (with some exceptions for points at the poles and equator...)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by a spherical coordinate system? These points are WGS84, so if I converted to $(x,y,z)$ and wanted them back, I would got to WGS84 not to another system.

Comment: I would have thought your first triplet of expressions is for *spherical* coordinates; 
your second triplet of expressions with $h=0$ is for *spheroid* coordinates; and your second triplet of expressions with $h\not=0$ is for spheroid coordinates plus an altitude above the surface